# File deletion very slow in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010

File deletion is very slow in Sharepoint 2010. It takes approximately 5 mts. to delete a 56KB file. What could be the cause and how to fix this?

Comment: I would guess there are around 1,000 factors which could affect this.  I don't know the answer, but you will surely need to give a massive amount more information to diagnose this.  What/where is the server?  The hardware?  The client?  How is the connection between the two?  How big is the site collection/site?  How many files?  How many security principals?  Etc.. etc..

Comment: do you have any event receiver attached to your list that trigger e.g. item deleting or deleted

Comment: i think you have to check file versions..
if you are frequently updating file then each time create new version. so it may be slow, you can set maximum version limit.

Comment: There is no event receiver attached to the list

Answer (score 3):

In my experience 99 of 100 performance issues you find the error on SQL Server, since SharePoint is a SQL Server intence product. Monitor the SQL Servers performance in terms of memory usage, processor usage, disk usage and network usage.

There is also a superb Wiki on the topic where you can start called [SharePoint 2010: Tips for Dealing with Performance Issues](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7926.sharepoint-2010-tips-for-dealing-with-performance-issues.aspx) where the three first is very general:

> - Get to know your application, it's usage, and it's response times by studying the IIS logs. One of the ways to do this is to use the free SharePoint Flavored Weblog Reader (SFWR) tool: http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/The-SharePoint-Flavored-5b03f323
> - Monitor performance counters that are relevant for SharePoint. The gallery post http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/PowerShell-script-for-59cf3f70   shows an overview of a set of relevant performance counters that have been established after careful research, and a small PowerShell script for reading them. Also see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff758658.aspx   for a different perspective.
> - Even if your environment is already up and running, do capacity planning. This way you can check if you're crossing any important limits that might threaten performance. Check out http://sharepointdragons.com/2011/12/05/sharepoint-capacity-planning/  and http://sharepointdragons.com/2012/02/03/more-capacity-planning-links/   . Also check out http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Maxer-for-SharePoint-2010-8cd0f26f    , Maxer for SharePoint 2010 is a tool that checks for capacity boundaries in existing SharePoint farms.  Do remember that content database limits include remote BLOBs (if you use them) and that auditing has a great impact on capacity planning: http://www.sharepointedutech.com/2011/07/11/sharepoint-contentdb-guidance-too-many-shades-of-gray-along-with-a-little-brown/

Further down the list you find more "hands-on advices":

> - Use SQL DMVs to analyze the state of your SQL database server, also taking into consideration the performance of other applications unrelated to SharePoint, but hosted on the same database server.
> - If you're allowed to: enable SQL Profiler to check SQL Server database problems on the fly.
> - Shrink the SharePoint content database transaction log files if they become too big or when it's size increases abnormally: http://sharepointdragons.com/2012/02/08/managing-sharepoint-2010-log-files/
> - Enable BLOB cache. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261797.aspx   , http://www.ittreats.com/microsoft/aspnet/configure-blob-cache-for-sharepoint-2010-web-applications.html
> - Enable Profile cache. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261797.aspx
> - Enable object cache. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261797.aspx
> - Enable output cache.

I hope that gives you something to start with!